# Drupal 7: Template for user registration page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

How would I make a template for the user registration page? I want to theme the entire page, not just the form. I've tried `page--user-register.tpl.php` but that does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `page--user--register.tpl.php` instead of `page--user-register.tpl.php`.

`page--user-register.tpl.php` changes the template for the page `user-register`, while `page--user--register.tpl.php` changes the template for the page `user/register`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)

It will show you all the template suggestions for any given page, and what to call them.  Also make sure you are clearing your cache.

Also [This is a great resource](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Answer (score 3):

Drupal out of the box does not provide any template suggestions for the registration form.  You'd need to write a custom module to add it.  You can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  $items = array(
    'user_register_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-register-form',
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Then you'd have a template in mymodule/templates called user-register-form.tpl.php which you can customize or override in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7

Add this code to your template.php in your theme directory.

```
    function yourtheme_theme() {
      return array(
        'user_login' => array(
          'template' => 'user-login',
          'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        ),
      );
    }

    function yourtheme_theme() {
      $items = array();
      $items['user_login'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-login',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
           'yourtheme_preprocess_user_login'
        ),
      );
      return $items;
    }

    function yourtheme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
      $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
    }
```

Create a file in your theme's "templates" folder called user-login.tpl.php.

Add this code and change "yourtheme" to your theme name.

```
 <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
```

Clear you cache.

Source (Where you can find details on how to do this for user-register-form, user-password-form, and Drupal 6)
https://drupal.org/node/350634

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be using "Panel" to create custon registration page :

1. Install and enable Panel Module
2. Create new page "registration page" and design the layout
3. Add content to your regions. For your case, the "registration block" or "login block"